# Why are eye defects so common?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, human-eye

The title says it all, what makes eye defects so common in the world? Whereas defects of any other body part is quite *uncommon*, I searched online and one of the articles said that 6 out of 10 people wear glasses, I think that is a big percentage of people with eye defects, BTW I'm myopic and I wear glasses too. Are all body parts defective to a certain degree, but It seems more pronounced in the case of eyes?

P.S

I know nothing about biology, I appreciate if someone could explain it with preferably less technical terms, this is my first question on BSE, let me know how I can make the post better.

Comment: @Roland I think that answers my question, you can mark this as a duplicate